# Matlab custom fit does not converge

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab 2018b. For some reason I cannot understand, custom fit performs poorly. I'm trying to perform a simple fit using the function 'y = a*exp(-b*x)+c' to find 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

When I use one of Matlab's saved codes, the fit converges without problems. However when I write it out myself, it does not.

I have given the code below. Does anyone have any insight into this?

```
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit1(d_10_45, dose_10_45)
%CREATEFIT1(D_10_45,DOSE_10_45)
%  Create a fit.
%
%  Data for 'untitled fit 1' fit:
%      X Input : d_10_45
%      Y Output: dose_10_45
%  Output:
%      fitresult : a fit object representing the fit.
%      gof : structure with goodness-of fit info.
%
%  另请参阅 FIT, CFIT, SFIT.

%  由 MATLAB 于 11-Aug-2019 13:20:36 自动生成


%% Fit: 'untitled fit 1'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( d_10_45, dose_10_45 );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'a*exp(-b*x)+c', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.StartPoint = [0.6611 0.0092359 0.2728];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );

% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'untitled fit 1' );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData );
legend( h, 'dose_10_45 vs. d_10_45', 'untitled fit 1', 'Location', 
'NorthEast' );
% Label axes
xlabel d_10_45
ylabel dose_10_45
grid on
```

Comment: Please show what the data looks like. How do you know that the model you're trying to fit works for the data? Is the posted code an example of _working_ or of _non-working_ code? If the model is good for the data, I would suspect that your initial guess is off. (I would also suggest increasing the number of iterations / function evaluations, but this is not needed if your guess is sufficiently good.) Also, what happens when you use the curve fitting tool (`cftool`)? It should tell you the reason for non-convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dev-iL. The data is hosted on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ki2zsf358nfkul7/DOSE_DEPTH.mat?dl=0. To answer your questions: (i) I'm sure the model is good for the data, since I've fitted it using Originlab and the built-in functions on Matlab (ii) the code should work because I used cftool to generate it. To re-iterate the problem, if I use cftool's inbuilft exponential function, it is able to do the fit. If I write out a custom equation  'y = a*exp(-b*x)+c' to do the fit, it is unable to give the correct answer even if I initialize in the same way.